# Query JSONB column data in Spanner DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, google-cloud-spanner

How do we query for a particular fields in an array element inside a json string
The column datatype is JSONB

```
Sample json

{ "data" : [ 
   { "begin" : "..." },
   { "inter" : "..." },
   { "inter" : "..." },
   { "skip" : ".." },
   { "inter" : "..." },
   { "final": ".."}
}
```

We need to find the values of "inter" in above json data string

I tried

`select colum_name ->> 'data' ->> 1 ->> 'inter'`

but the index is not limited to one value , rather range of values as inter key can be anywhere in the list

Answer (score 0):

Try below query that uses  `jsonb_array_elements(your_column->'data')` to unnest the array elements of the JSONB data, allowing us to iterate over each element. Then, the `->>` operator is used to extract the text value of the 'inter' key from these elements. A `WHERE` clause is included to filter out elements without the 'inter' key and to ensure that the operation is only performed on array data types.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements(your_column->'data') ->> 'inter' as inter_value
FROM your_table
WHERE jsonb_typeof(your_column->'data') = 'array' AND 
      jsonb_array_elements(your_column->'data') ? 'inter';
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten/unnest the JSON column array using `jsonb_array_elements` and a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL), filter by "`inter` attribute exists".

```sql
select j ->> 'inter' as inter -- <other expressions here>
from the_table,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(the_json_column::jsonb -> 'data') as j
where j ? 'inter';
```